# "came in" in writing

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

I often read books by different authors and each one has their own way of using verbs and the sentence-structures are often very strange. I was just wondering if from the point of view of Modern English grammar both variants of "**Then the King came in**" are correct:

- Then in came the King.
- Then came in the King.

I think it's only used in poetic English and is very old-fashioned. I can't say whether or not it is correct English but it sounds amazing.

Comment: I don't like the first one. I feel like the verb "came" intterupts the prepositional phrase constituent.

Comment: "Then came in the King" is fine. This inversion is likely when the sentence has an initial adverbial.

Comment: @user178049 I disagree - if you are just using it as a sentence the first one makes sense and the second one doesn't. If you are saying a list of people entering somewhere, you can use the first one or drop the "in".

Comment: @SteveES Both make sense and express a complete thought. But the first one sounds very wrong to my daily practiced ears. And why doesn't the second one make sense? In my experience, it sounds perfectly fine just like "Down came the rain and washed the spider out".

Comment: @user178049 I'm fairly sure I've read books that use the "in came x" structure. My problem with the second is the position of the "in" - without "in" it's fine. "in came the king" is the same structure as "out came the sun"; saying "came out the sun" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @user178049 To me, the second reads as [then came] [in the king], which doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SteveES Now I agree that "in came the King" is OK.

Comment: Even today, we use: "Then in came Johnny, claiming he saw his brother earlier that day". "Then in came [some person]" is used when you are describing a scene to a person who was not there when it occurred. In any event, the second form is never grammatical. The first is. There is always an implied place; Then Johnny came in [to the room, the party, etc.]

Answer (score 4):

Both are valid forms.

The first

> Then *in* came the King.

is found usually in storytelling contexts. Moving the preposition before the verb and the subject after the verb puts greater emphasis on preposition and verb, all for dramatic effect. Compare "Then down came the rain" and "Out came the sun":

```
The itsy bitsy spider climbed up the waterspout.
Down came the rain
and washed the spider out.
Out came the sun
and dried up all the rain
and the itsy bitsy spider climbed up the spout again.
```

The role of many prepositions is to define the unfolding of action in *space-time*.  Moving the preposition to a position of greater prominence draws greater attention to the elemental physical aspect of the action. The rain is *falling*. The sun *emerges* from the clouds.

The inverted word order in the second sentence (*Then came in the King*) is an archaism found mainly in storytelling contexts. Nowadays we would add **there**:

> Then tumbled in six acrobats.
>
> Then there tumbled in six acrobats.
>
> There tumbled in six acrobats.
>
> Tumbled in six acrobats. <sub>not used</sub>

In the mode of #1:

> In tumbled six acrobats.

Comment: I really dislike "in came the King". Can a prepositional phrase be interupted like that? What's the rule behind it?

Comment: What is the "prepositional phrase" there? I don't see one.

Comment: I believe "in the king" in "came in the king" is a contituent of a prepositional phrase.

Comment: You are mistaken.  **in** is what used to be called an *adverb*.  It has no object here.  **in** describes direction of motion.

Comment: I don't think the second version _is_ ok (although I'm not sure I can explain exactly why and I'm happy to be proved wrong)

Comment: Oh, btw, I found the examples without "**in**" in the lyrics of Dire straits - Telegraph Road song. *"Then came the churches, then came the schools, then came the lawyers, then came the rules, then came the trains and the trucks with their load, and the dirty old track was the Telegraph Road"*